# Fool python that it is called from tty

Tags: python, shell

The question is somewhat opposite to the [Fool python's os.isatty from a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041963/fool-pythons-os-isatty-from-a-bash-script). I need python script to think that its stdin is attached to the tty.

In particular, I need to use some script, that changes its behavior depending on sys.stdin.isatty(). But when python is called in a bash loop, stdin.isatty() returns false

```
cat 'file.txt' | while read ENTRY
do
python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.isatty()"
done
```

So is there a way to maybe wrap that call, so python will think that it is called from the tty.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @tangrs: Comes in useful in case a program behaves differently depending on whether called from a TTY or not; most cases involve delayed flushing of output which is buried deep in the libc already, so affects also Python scripts.

Comment: In your case, the stdin of the Python script is _not_ a TTY but the pipe of the `cat` command before the while loop.  And that command is not a TTY.

Comment: @Alfe Oh, now I really got why it didn't work, because otherwise it looks to strange for me. Maybe I should clarify in the question, that it is because of the `cat`, to eliminate misunderstanding? Sorry, but it is my first question here and I'm too afraid of everything.

Comment: @tangrs Honestly, it is for this issue https://github.com/VitaliyRodnenko/geeknote/issues/135 . I am not the author of the issue, and have no relation to the geeknote, but I saw that issue, and became curious why it is so. It appears that in geeknote, there is confusing decision, that if stdin is not on the tty, it tries to read it, forgetting everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could just try to redirect the input of the Python script alone:

```
cat 'file.txt' | while read ENTRY
do
  python -c "import sys; print sys.stdin.isatty()" < /dev/tty
done
```